# Comprimento inválido para uma cadeia ou matriz de caracteres de Base-64. Erro ao descriptografar String

Tags: c#

Preciso de uma ajuda, estou utilizando um código de criptografia e ao fazer o login me retorna este erro:

> 'Comprimento inválido para uma cadeia ou matriz de caracteres de Base-64'.

Código de criptografia:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace SGA.database
{
    class CryptographyManager
    {
        public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
            byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return clearText;
        }      
    }
}
```

Este é código de descriptografar:

```
        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
            {
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
                encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
                encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                        cs.Close();
                    }
                    cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }
            return cipherText;
        }
```

Comment: Seu código está funcionando normalmente, o que pode acontecer é algo que respondi aqui nessa pergunta:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/281383/erro-ao-converter-base64-para-string/281395#281395

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pois o autor da pergunta nunca mais retornou para dar mais informações