# Erro ao converter base64 para String

Tags: c#

Eu tenho uma string base64 mas o compilador do C# diz que ela não é válida, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> A entrada não é uma cadeia de caracteres de Base 64 válida, pois contém um caractere que não é de base 64, mais de dois caracteres de preenchimento ou um caractere ilegal entre os caracteres de preenchimento.

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
String s_data = "RmluYWwtUmVjaXBpZW50OiByZmM4MjI7IGd1YXJhbmFicmFzaWxAZ3VhcmFuYXN0b2NrLmNvbQ0KQWN0aW9uOiBmYWlsZWQNClN0YXR1czogNS4wLjANCkRpYWdub3N0aWMtQ29kZTogc210cDsgVGhlIGVtYWlsIGFjY291bnQgdGhhdCB5b3UgdHJpZWQgdG8gcmVhY2ggZG9lcyBub3QgZXhpc3QuIFBsZWFzZSB0cnkgZG91YmxlLWNoZWNraW5nIHRoZSByZWNpcGllbnQncyBlbWFpbCBhZGRyZXNzIGZvciB0eXBvcyBvciB1bm5lY2Vzc2FyeSBzcGFjZXMuIExlYXJuIG1vcmUgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly9zdXBwb3J0Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vbWFpbC8_cD1Ob1N1Y2hVc2VyIG40c29yMzk2MDY5M3dtaC4zNCAtIGdzbXRwDQpMYXN0LUF0dGVtcHQtRGF0ZTogV2VkLCAwNyBNYXIgMjAxOCAwOTo1MToxNiAtMDgwMCAoUFNUKQ0K";
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(s_data);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Eu testei a `string` de `data` [nesse site](https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode) e lá converte normalmente. Eu já converti outras `strings` em `base64` porém essa está dando problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece porque na conversão para Base64 algumas vezes caracteres alteram de `+` e `/` para `-` e `_`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history

Segue exemplo funcionando 
http://rextester.com/LJLLZO44181

```
String s_data = "RmluYWwtUmVjaXBpZW50OiByZmM4MjI7IGd1YXJhbmFicmFzaWxAZ3VhcmFuYXN0b2NrLmNvbQ0KQWN0aW9uOiBmYWlsZWQNClN0YXR1czogNS4wLjANCkRpYWdub3N0aWMtQ29kZTogc210cDsgVGhlIGVtYWlsIGFjY291bnQgdGhhdCB5b3UgdHJpZWQgdG8gcmVhY2ggZG9lcyBub3QgZXhpc3QuIFBsZWFzZSB0cnkgZG91YmxlLWNoZWNraW5nIHRoZSByZWNpcGllbnQncyBlbWFpbCBhZGRyZXNzIGZvciB0eXBvcyBvciB1bm5lY2Vzc2FyeSBzcGFjZXMuIExlYXJuIG1vcmUgYXQgaHR0cHM6Ly9zdXBwb3J0Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20vbWFpbC8_cD1Ob1N1Y2hVc2VyIG40c29yMzk2MDY5M3dtaC4zNCAtIGdzbXRwDQpMYXN0LUF0dGVtcHQtRGF0ZTogV2VkLCAwNyBNYXIgMjAxOCAwOTo1MToxNiAtMDgwMCAoUFNUKQ0K";
string converted = s_data.Replace('-', '+');
converted = converted.Replace('_', '/');
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(converted);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Valeu, eu percebi que eu fazia essa alteração quando eu ia codificar, mas não fazia quando ia decodificar. Funcionou obg